# Java version determination error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-5

I just install Android Studio 1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. I created a new project and I get the following error:

```
Error:Could not determine Java version using executable /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java.
```

My `/usr/lib/jvm/` contain:

```
java-1.5.0-gcj            java-7-oracle  java-gcj
java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64  java-8-oracle  java-gcj-4.8
```

The Project Structure has the JDK location set up to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj`. Should it me something else ? How can I know ?

Many thanks for you help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by simply changing the JDK to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. I still don't know why it works, or why it should have been like this at the first place. 
Sorry for the question.

Comment: I think the Java executable is executed with -version and the information parsed. And the output of your gcj does not equal what is expected which is based on the strings given by Oracle

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because location of the JDK directory was not defined correctly.
In Android studio File ->Project structure ->in left side tabs click on SDK location->define the directory where JDK is located .
For example:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_77 is my directory of JDK.The location can be different.

Answer (score -2):

Another variant:

Replace `homePath` value in `~/.AndroidStudio1.5/config/options/jdk.table.xml` on `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java`