# Android studio - java version error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to use android studio on my pc with Linux Mint 64 bit.
I've installed java-8-oracle following this:
[Error to run Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601334/error-to-run-android-studio)
Now, when I start a new project, it returns a message to me with:

"Error:Could not determine Java version using executable /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/bin/java."

Now, I'm following this:
[Java version determination error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072267/java-version-determination-error)

but at the moment I can't fix it...
Can you help me?
Many thanks!

Comment: have you added Java in the System path?

Comment: In etc/environment I have:
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/$
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"

Comment: I find it in File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs. There I change JDK home path.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem. Modified path to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle through File -> Project Structure -> JDK location

Error message disappeared

Answer (score -1):

My enviroment text didnt allow me change JAVA_HOME location .For this reason I went to file->project structure and changed my jdk directory and it worked .By the way I am using XUbuntu 14.04.